# Adding cookie to Appium Android Driver

Tags: android, cookies, appium

Am automating an android App using appium android driver with saucelabs.
I was trying to add a cookie to the driver, but its not working.

Exception thrown:
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

Tried driver.manage().addCookie()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.